# Easily replicate browser requests with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently trying to write a small bot for a banking site that doesn't supply an API. Nevertheless, the security of the login page seems a little more ingenious than what I'd have expected, since even though I don't see any significant difference between Chrome and Python, it doesn't let requests made by Python through (I accounted for things such as headers and cookies)

I've been wondering if there is a tool to record requests in FireFox/Chrome/Any browser and replicate them in Python (or any other language)? Think selenium, but without the overhead of selenium :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium web drivers to actually use browsers to make the requests for you.

In such cases, I usually checkout the request made by Chrome from my dev tools "Network" tab. Then I right click on the request and copy the request as cURL to run it on command line to see if it works perfectly. If it does, then I can be certain it can be achieved using Python's requests package.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) or [casperjs](http://casperjs.org). That is a complete browser that can be programmed using JavaScript